# Redux infinite scroll in a container

Tags: javascript, redux, reactjs, react-redux

I have used the Redux-infinite-scroll library for implementing infinite scroll.

```
<ul className = "list">
                    <InfiniteScroll
                        loadMore={this.props.loadMOre}
                        loadingMore={this.props.isFetching}
                        hasMore={this.props.finished}
                        elementIsScrollable={true}
                        containerHeight="300px"
                    >
                        {this.props.list.map((el) => <li>{el}</li>)}
                    </InfiniteScroll>
                </ul>
```

but this is not working. not able to figure out why. After some debugging i got that it is not able find the overflow of the div.

Comment: Spelling? `loadMOre`

Comment: If you want to use librabry its well n good, but if you want see how it actually works you can check https://github.com/jinxac/sound-redux out once. They have implemented this in a nice way.